# Error System.BadImageFormatException service fabric

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

## Problem

I am building service fabric application. When I create a Project and run it its working fine. but when I inject a service in the Api controller it gives me this error I tried to resolved it but not succeeded yet.

## Error

> System.BadImageFormatException
> Could not load file or assembly 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator-design' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

## Image

[image]

I add the service

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
            {
                new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                    new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
                    {
                        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                        return new WebHostBuilder()
                                    .UseKestrel()
                                    .ConfigureServices(
                                        services => services
                                            .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext)
                                            .AddScoped(typeof(ISendMessage), typeof(SendMessage))
                                            )
                                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                    .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                                    .UseUrls(url)
                                    .Build();
                    }))
            };
        }
```

Comment: Make sure all dependencies are 64 bit, as Service Fabric only supports 64 bits applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Service Fabric System.BadImageFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307850/service-fabric-system-badimageformatexception)

Comment: @PeterBons all projects are x64, as for making sure that the nuget packages are x64, i woudlnt know how to do

Answer (score 4):

It is likely that your service or any of their dependencies is targeting a *x86 platform*.

To fix that, you have to force your service running on **x64** and/or replace any *x86* dependencies for **x64**.

If your are running dotnet-core, make sure the x64 tools are installed as well.

You might also try removing the reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` from your project as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801045/badimageformatexception-when-migrating-from-asp-net-core-1-1-to-2-0)

> These SO questions might give you more information:
>
> [service fabric system badimageformatexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307850/service-fabric-system-badimageformatexception?noredirect=1&lq=1)
>
> [badimageformatexception when migrating from aspnet core 1.1 to
>   2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801045/badimageformatexception-when-migrating-from-asp-net-core-1-1-to-2-0)

Comment: how do i ensure that the dotnet core tools are x64?

Comment: Probably the easiest way to check is verifying the path on Environment variables. Go to your command promp(cmd) and type path, it will list the paths for installed softwares, dotnet will be one of them. if it is x86, it will be installed on "c:\program files (x86)\dotnet". if it is x64, it will be installed on "c:\program files\dotnet". If you have both, Go to environment variables and reorder them to have x64 first.
Environement variable is located on: Right Click on "This Pc" > Properties > Advanced System settings > Environment Variables > System Variables.

Comment: neither one is installed

Answer (score 3):

This was an issue we faced sometime ago, It comes when you try to add asp.net core controller. For some reason visual studio adds the reference to "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design".

My sugegstion would be to remove the reference and also not add controller using the Project->Add->Controller. [image]

Just add a basic code file and copy the content from an earlier controller. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, simply follow the steps below:

> - open project properties window.
> - select Build tab
> - Change it to ‘Any CPU’
> - Save your changes.
> - Compile your project and run
>     [image]

- From source [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/hosamkamel/resolved-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-xxxxx-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format)

## Edit 1:

> [Service febric targets x64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore) bit then Click the Platform dropdown and choose New, then create an x64 platform configuration.

Comment: service fabric projects **must** be x64

Comment: then im not sure how valueable your answer is

Answer (score 1):

Add more binaries for the package, and do AnyCPU for the platform target.

```
<PackageId>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design</PackageId>
 <RuntimeIdentifier Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' != 'netcoreapp2.0' ">win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
 <RuntimeIdentifier Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' != 'netcoreapp2.0' ">win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```